# finding difference between 2 files

Tags: shell, unix

I want to find the difference between two files and print only the unique lines.

I tried with `uniq -u`, its not working.

```
diff test.sh  test1.sh > test.txt
sort test.txt | uniq -u > test1.txt
```

How else I can do the same?

Comment: IMO sorting a shell scripts lines doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
> cat 1
1
2
3
4
> cat 2
2
3
4
5
> cat 1 2 | sort | uniq -u
1
5
```

Comment: `sort 1 2 | uniq -u`   UUOC http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html